# Behat with Selenium Hub and Firefox Error: Could not open connection: Payload received from webdriver is valid but unexpected json

Tags: selenium, firefox, docker, selenium-grid, behat

I'm trying to run Behat on Docker using `selenium/hub`, `selenium/node-chrome-debug` and `selenium/node-firefox-debug` images.

Running Behat with the Chrome node is working, but the Firefox node gives me the following error:

```
Could not open connection: Payload received from webdriver is valid but unexpected json: {"value":{"sessionId":"244f4715-c59b-4bfc-aa17-8f6a867ead83","capabilities":{"moz:profile":"/tmp/rust_mozprofile.u3mB4xKf6nVD","rotatable":false,"timeouts":{"implicit":0,"pageLoad":300000,"script":30000},"pageLoadStrategy":"normal","moz:headless":false,"moz:accessibilityChecks":false,"acceptInsecureCerts":false,"browserVersion":"57.0","platformVersion":"4.9.60-linuxkit-aufs","moz:processID":1005,"browserName":"firefox","platformName":"linux","moz:webdriverClick":false}}} (Behat\Mink\Exception\DriverException)
```

When I `vnc` to Firefox node, I see it opened Firefox, but nothing is happening.

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  site.local:
    image: webdevops/php-apache-dev:7.1
    ports:
      - "8888:80"
    volumes:
      - ./public:/app
      - .:/application

  selenium-grid-hub.local:
    image: selenium/hub
    ports:
      - "4445:4444"

  selenium-node-chrome.local:
    image: selenium/node-chrome-debug
    environment:
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=selenium-grid-hub.local
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
    ports:
      - "5901:5900"

  selenium-node-firefox.local:
    image: selenium/node-firefox-debug
    environment:
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=selenium-grid-hub.local
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
    ports:
      - "5902:5900"
```

My `behat.yml`:

```
default:
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      base_url: "http://site.local"
      goutte:
        guzzle_parameters:
          verify: false
  suites:
    mysuite:
      paths:    [ %paths.base%/features ]
      contexts:
        - Zstate\BehatSeleniumDockerSkeleton\Tests\Behat\Context\FeatureContext

chrome:
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      selenium2:
        browser: "chrome"
        wd_host: http://selenium-grid-hub.local:4444/wd/hub
        capabilities: {"browserName": "chrome", "browser": "chrome", 'chrome': {'switches':['--no-sandbox']}}

firefox:
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      selenium2:
        browser: "firefox"
        wd_host: http://selenium-grid-hub.local:4444/wd/hub
        capabilities: {"browserName": "firefox", "browser": "firefox"}
```

I created this small [repo](https://github.com/zstate/behat-selenium-docker-skeleton) to replicate the issue.

I would greatly appreciate any help or advice. Please let me know if I miss something in my question so I can update it.

Comment: I think this is an issue with the firefox node image. Which Versions are you running ? I have the same in a different place and the returned values are only a subset of the expected. The 'status' and the 'sessionId' are missing.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has the same error, this was what helped me.
In my case, the way to solve it was by establishing the following:

for chrome:

```
capabilities: {"extra_capabilities":{"chromeOptions":{"w3c":false}}}
```

More info [here](https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium/issues/328#issuecomment-548454672).